TZ variable inside container that does not have tzdata installed
I have a couple questions about TZ variable inside a container and TZ variable overall.
First: when I have a container, let's say for example busybox:1.28 image that does not have the tzdata information, I understand that export TZ=America/Los_Angeles will not work ( as expected ), but why export TZ=GMT+7 works ?
Why linux/apps can understand GMT+7 ( without having any /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT file )?
My second question, also TZ related is:
If i want to use for example the TZ for Sao_Paulo ( which I know is 3 hours less than UTC ), why do I need to export TZ=GMT+3 and NOT export TZ=GMT-3 ?
Thanks!

Why linux/apps can understand GMT+7 without having any /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT file? why would an app not understand GMT? GMT/UTC have nothing to do with time zones, every application and operating system understands it.

The correct POSIX/traditional (non-tzdata) setting for US Pacific time (including California) is PST[+]8PDT[[+]7] (the plus signs are optional and the second offset defaults to the first -1). The docker images for busybox support 3 different C libraries but if you don't specify it's glibc and glibc supports both the POSIX formats AND the tzdata (Olson/IANA) filename format

....but specifying standard + daylight time offsets won't work without a TZ database since the OS doesn't know WHEN to switch between the options.
